# Microsoft Universal App Webview' source does not show url

Tags: webview, win-universal-app

I am very new in universal app development. Maybe It is very easy question.
I tried to use webview like iframe but It doesn't show my url.It was successed source url with google etc. Here is my code:

```
    <Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView Source="http://appstest.local/Survey" x:Name="WebView" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1280"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Is it about proxy setting? Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) can only display some basic information of a website, from the source you used I can see that you to display your own website want. How is your website's implementation?

Comment: It's basic Mvc web project and hosted on iis. I can call my own site on every browser. Also I can display both my site on localhost and universal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply tested it with a basic MVC web project, it works well when using the localhost address as Url source.

> Source="http://appstest.local/Survey"

From your Url, you may use a private host for your website, for this scenario, you will need to add the `Private Networks (Client & Server)` capability in the manifest file of your project:
[image]

> The privateNetworkClientServer capability provides inbound and outbound access to home and work networks through the firewall. This capability is typically used for games that communicate across the local area network (LAN), and for apps that share data across a variety of local devices.

You can refer to [App capability declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270968.aspx).